# Can`t think of better way to model the database

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to create a demo project where there are 3 tables: `category`, `model`, `type`.

There may be different categories, such as `cellphone`, `tablets`, `computer`, etc. For each category there are different types, such as for `cellphone` there could be `asus`, `iphone`, `nokia`, etc. Likewise, for each type there are  different models: for nokia there might be `nokia`, `lumia`, `nokia n97`, etc. How do I create this database in symfony2 using annotations?

Comment: The first step is trying

Comment: Follow the Symfony2 docs. When you stumble on a problem, open a question with your code included.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed because you have not showed what you have already tried. Also, note that you're talking about a 'one to many relationship' between category and type, and type and model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not that complicated:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Category
{   
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Model", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $models;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Model
{   
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="models")
     * @JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/        
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Type", mappedBy="model")
     */
    private $types;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Type
{   
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Model", inversedBy="types")
     * @JoinColumn(name="model_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/        
    private $model;
}
```

After adding your code each one in it's file run the command:
`php app/console doctrine:generate:entities`
and it will generate setters and getters and constructors